# Memory leak and performance leak in Fiddler2

Tags: performance, memory-leaks, fiddler

I'm using fiddler2 to substitute certain requests to the webserver. Those requests occur about 10 per second. Fiddler performance is falling down with time, about 1 hour of work and then it starts lagging on proxing response. Also memory usage grows. This could be solved with restart of fiddler.

I suspect this is caused by growing log size and some scanning operation on whole request log, which runs on each request.

Is there any way to configure fiddler to avoid such leaks? Maybe some way to reset it's memory or logging data by fiddler rules, or set limit to its size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For scenarios like this, you want to ensure that Fiddler is dropping traffic as soon as it's done with it. The simplest way to do that is to set the **Keep only** dropdown on Fiddler's toolbar so that it discards Sessions as they are completed.

See http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Troubleshoot-Fiddler/OutOfMemory for other tricks you can use to accommodate large responses, streaming data, etc.

Comment: Filtering requests might also be of some help here. `keep sessions` + valid filters will keep memory usage at stable level, am I right master @EricLaw? :)

Comment: Setting filters is basically equivalent to dropping the traffic using the Keep only dropdown. Setting Filters (e.g. the Hide all traffic option in the status bar) will also improve UI performance.

Comment: The **Keep only** dropdown option doesn't really work. I always have it set to 100-250 requests. In this case there's no way over time Fiddler should start consuming more than 1GB of ram which it does. Because if it only had the 100 lines of requests in memory which I can see it should not need 1GB of RAM.

Comment: BTW, I'm not dealing with large files either.

Comment: @EdwardOlamisan Rather than continuing this discussion unproductively in comments, why not move over to the Fiddler discussion group, where you can provide useful details about whatever problem you're having?

Comment: Here's a similar question https://groups.google.com/d/msg/httpfiddler/1yraVutAHTc/pJf-wS-9ktIJ <b\> And the official answer I guess: _"Keep in mind that due to the nature of .NET's Garbage Collector and Windows' memory manager even when you do this, Fiddler will likely continue to hold more in memory than it truly needs until there's memory pressure from other applications."_

Comment: Had a similar situation. Thx @EricLaw  Choosing 'Hide all traffic' and setting oSession.bBufferResponse = false; in OnPeekAtResponseHeaders handler made it go away.